# iOS Photos Crashes

Tags: ios, ipad, icloud, photos

I recently merged a library of about 110,000 photos into my iCloud Photos library, using an iMac running Sierra. The process went slowly, but well and I can see the photos on other Macs and on my iPhone 6S running iOS 10. However, my iPad Air 2 started often crashing when I loaded the Photos app. At first it was intermittent, but now it is constant. I've tried disabling iCloud Photo Library, but it still crashes. I've alternated between downloading all photos and optimizing storage and that does no good. I've tried force quitting the Photos app, restarting the iPad, etc. Today, I even downloaded the latest beta of iOS 11 to see if that might do the trick -- the Photos app still crashes.

Is there a way to completely reset the Photos app without wiping my iPad as a whole? Is there another way to try to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Considering what you have already done it seems like something in the filesystem may be damaged. Whether it is a preference file of some sort, a bad photo or even a damaged app, there is no way to tell.

Apple has chosen to keep the guts of IOS hidden and inaccessible (well unless you're a dev or a jailbreaker...) making troubleshooting this both more problematic and simpler.

So you can't open the photolibrary file or delete preferences files like you can on macOS. Which would be suggestions you would see on a Mac.

I am afraid your best method of fixing this is backing up the iPad, then wiping it completely and then restoring from the backup. Simple but (possibly) annoying.

Comment: Thank you, @Steve. I attempted this process and it seemed to fix the issue at first. Then, Photos started crashing occasionally again. Now, as of a day or two ago, it has returned to its old state of a empty photos screen appearing, the app freezing for about 20 seconds and crashing. This is with iOS 11 GM.

Comment: One then wonders if there is a damaged/malformed pic that IOS photos can't handle, maybe.. not sure.